# I have Protected Custom Metadata Object Relationship field and I can't make it Unique

Tags: managed-package, custom-field, unique-field, unique

I have Protected Custom Metadata Object Relationship field and I can't make it Unique.
When I try to make it unique and generate a new validated package version, I receive the following error:

> CustomMetadataMapping__mdt.TargetObject__c: Cannot modify managed
> object: entity=CustomFieldDefinition, component=00N1X00000Li061,
> state=MANAGED_RELEASED, Field: IsIndexed Previous Value: false New
> Value: true

I don't change any indexing here, why do I receive this error and have can I overcome this?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like it is forbidden to change unique attribute on Fields in Managed package even if the custom metadata type is protected. Salesforce thinks there might be records with duplicated values and forbids to change the unique attribute when a new package version is released